# Template constructor

Tags: c++

The problem: I find myself faced with numerous duplicate functions to support different types of almost-identical array-like inputs. For example, a function foo might be available in the following versions:

```
void foo (int v); // single value, 99% of all use cases.
void foo (std::initializer_list<int> v);
void foo (const std::vector<int> &v);
void foo (int *v, int size);
```

This duplication bothers me. I would like to have a single function foo, that may be called with any kind of array-like data (with a single value obviously being seen as an array of size 1).

Possible solutions include:

- Always use the vector version. This incurs some overhead for memory allocation on every use, and since 99% of my uses are for single values I find this undesirable.
- Have an interface specifying an iterator pair. This again falls flat when attempting to call the function for a single value.
- Have some sort of abstraction for array-like data that can handle all of the desired input types. This is a promising approach, but I do run into some trouble...

My implementation is called mem_range, which presents a vector-like interface (only including operations that do not change the size of the vector, obviously). The various types of arrays are supposed to be handled through different constructors of mem_range.

I have trouble specifying the constructor that is supposed to take std::array. The problem is the array size, which is part of the template definition - I cannot figure out how to create a constructor that will accept arrays of any size.

```
template<typename T>
class mem_range {
    public:
        mem_range (T *begin, T *end) { } // ok
        mem_range (std::vector<T> &vec) { } // ok

        template<int array_size>
        mem_range<array_size> (std::array<T, array_size> &arr) { } // not ok
}
```

The last constructor yields "error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition" on MSVC2015. I've gone through quite a few variations now, but nothing that makes the compiler happy.

Just to be clear, based on answers I've read on similar questions here on stackoverflow:

- Resizing the array-like data in any way is not in scope. If I wanted that capability I'd just pass an std::vector.
- I'm aware there are many questions with similar titles. None of these appear to have decent answers, usually getting no further than "why do you want this?".

I'm trying to make this work on MSVC2015 and modern GCC, so C++14/17 are fine (as far as supported).

Comment: when you're writing code, write it as simple and straightforward as you can -- don't worry about optimizations until later when you have an actual data set to profile against.  Worrying about the cost of building a 1 element array is probably not going to be something that will make or break your program -- keeping bugs out by building it simple, though, could save you from some serious headaches later.

Comment: It's a 300,000 line system used for high-performance scientific analysis, and performance noticably dropped when I attempted to unify all those functions into a single (vector-based) version. I've been working on it for almost 20 years, I hope that qualifies as 'later' in your book...

Comment: "This incurs some overhead for memory allocation on every use, and since 99% of my uses are for single values I find this undesirable." doesn't really convey that information..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When declaring the templated constructor, the template is understood to belong to the constructor function, so you don't need to specify it there.

You are also missing a closing bracket `>` after the array argument.

So the constructor should look like this:

```
template<int array_size>
mem_range(std::array<T, array_size>) { }
```

---

And of course, you should consider passing the array object as a reference to a constant, and using the correct type (see e.g. [this `std::array` reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)), i.e.

```
template<std::size_t array_size>
mem_range(std::array<T, array_size> const&) { }
```

Comment: `std::array` uses `std::size_t` and not `int` btw.

Comment: While I'm pretty sure I did try this variation at some point, I must have done something wrong at that time - this works. Thanks! Also, regarding the size_t thing - thanks as well, I'll take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

You can make array_size an optional value of the template class.

```
template<typename T, int array_size=0>
class mem_range {
public:
    mem_range (T *begin, T *end) { } // ok
    mem_range (std::vector<T> &vec) { } // ok
    mem_range (std::array<T, array_size> &array) { }
}
```